# Resetting message sequence numbers without reconnecting

Tags: c#, .net, quickfix

since official QuickFix website is not working, I am asking here. 
I am trying to meet my broker's (FXCM) demands for API readiness. I am using quickfix .NET v1.13.3. One of the demands was that I need to reset the sequence numbers once a day and the connection must be still working. But when I reset the sequence numbers using:

```
QuickFix.Session.lookupSession(mSessionID).setNextSenderMsgSeqNum(1);
QuickFix.Session.lookupSession(mSessionID).setNextTargetMsgSeqNum(1);
```

the connection reconnects. Is there any way to reset it without loging out?

My configuration file:

```
[DEFAULT]

#client connection
ConnectionType=initiator

#Logon & Logout timers
LogonTimeout=1
LogoutTimeout=1

ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=Y
ValidateUserDefinedFields=Y
ValidateFieldsHaveValues=Y
AllowUnknownMsgFields=Y
SocketTcpNoDelay=Y

FileStorePath=Store

CheckLatency=N
CheckCompID=Y

SendRedundantResendRequests=Y
ContinueInitializationOnError=Y

ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
ForceResync=Y

[SESSION]

#login info
username=****
password=****

#protocol version 4.4
BeginString=FIX.4.4

#database and compid
SenderCompID=*****
TargetCompID=*****
TargetSubID=******

HeartBtInt=30
StartTime=01:00:00
EndTime=22:00:00
StartDay=Mon
EndDay=Fri
UseLocalTime=Y

ReconnectInterval=20

#data dictionary
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=FXService.FXCM.xml
```

I found in the logs in logout message this error:

```
MsgSeqNum too low, expecting 12 but received 3
```

So I believe the error is in the timing of my reseting. When is it safe to reset the sequence numbers and how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ResetOnLogon=Y 
ResetOnLogout=Y 
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
```

You are resetting the message sequence numbers, by default, when you login/logout/disconnect. So when you reset the sequence number, in your code after having set up a session, it would be rejected by the other party.

Your only option is to read the reject message and use the sequence number mentioned in the reject message, if you do not want to disconnect from the existing connection. Resetting sequence numbers in an already existing session is going to be a nuisance i.e. reconstruct the message with the correct sequence number and then re-transmit it. Better only reset sequences when you logon/logoff/disconnect which the quickfix engine will do it by default as you have set the flags in the config file.

Comment: Thanks, so far I am working on another projects and have no time for this. But I have decided to let quickfix manage my sequence number on its own.